# vb.net loop through textbox controls in containers

Tags: vb.net, textbox, controls, containers

My question may be simple but it's killing me...

I Have a windows user form with on it tabcontrols (about 10x).
On each tabcontrol i have some groupbox controls with in them some textboxes.

Tree structure would be something like this.

```
-Tab1
--Groupbox1
---Textbox name Alg_0
---Textbox name Alg_1
---Textbox name Alg_2
---Textbox name Alg_3
--Groupbox2
---Textbox name Alg_4
---Textbox name Alg_5
---Textbox name Alg_6
---Textbox name Alg_7
-Tab2
--Groupbox3
---Textbox name DD_0
---Textbox name DD_1
---Textbox name DD_2
---Textbox name DD_3
--Groupbox4
---Textbox name DD_4
---Textbox name DD_5
---Textbox name DD_6
---Textbox name DD_7
And many more (but in the same spirit)
```

What i want to do is loop through theses text boxes to create a comma seperated line and the write the values to a .txt file for saving. Later i will load these values and continue working with them.

Example (the names will be values ofcourse):

```
Alg_0,Alg_1,Alg_2,Alg_3,Alg_4,Alg_5,Alg_6,Alg_7,
```

I tried using the `me.controls("String here")` method. But this appears not to be working when the controls are in a container.

Example:

```
Private Sub main_save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles main_save.Click

    Dim oID As Integer
    Dim oEnd As Integer
    Dim oAlg As String
    Dim oDD As String

    For oID = 0 To oEnd = 7
        oAlg = Me.Controls("Alg_" & oID).Text & ","
    Next

    For oID = 0 To oEnd = 7
        oDD = Me.Controls("DD_" & oID).Text & ","
    Next

End Sub
```

/At the end will be a writeline code which i will add later here./

For my **Question**
How do i access these textboxes in this order when they are in the containers as described?

Comment: INstead of `Me.Controls` its `GroupBox1.Controls`

Answer (score 3):

You could try with something like this

```
for each tp in tabControl.Controls.OfType(Of TabPage)()
    for each gp in tp.Controls.OfType(Of GroupBox)()
        for each tx in gp.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
            sb.Append(tx.Text & ",")
        Next
    Next
Next
```

This method takes the tabControl that contains the various tabPage and for each tabPage search the page ControlCollection for controls of type GroupBox then, for each groupbox search its controls collection for TextBoxes and prepare the output text

On the contrary you could take the string produced here to restore the textboxes with similar code

```
Dim texts = lineFromFile.Split(",")
Dim index as Integer = 0

for each tp in tabControl.Controls.OfType(Of TabPage)()
    for each gp in tp.Controls.OfType(Of GroupBox)()
        for each tx in gp.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
            tx.Text = texts(index)
            index = index+1
        Next
    Next
Next
```

I should add that this approach is rather weak and you could face many problems to restore the values if you change in any way the layout of your form